# Java String token

Tags: java, regex

I have read the `String.split` Javadoc, and I also read [How to split a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

I was trying this code, and my delimiters are

**!,?._'@**

However, it doesn't `split`. What's wrong with my code?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  { 
    String[] tokens = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?".split(" !,\\?\\._'@");
    for (String token : tokens){
      System.out.println(token);
    }
  }
}
```

The output should be

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

But instead, I get

```
He is a very very good boy, isn't he?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited :

```
public class Solution {
 public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

       String[] tokens = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?".split("[ |!|,|\\?|\\.|_|'|@|]+");
       for(String token : tokens){
       System.out.println(token);
       }
      }
     }
```

Try this out...

Comment: @Rishi..Actually I don't want a space between boy and isn?I have edited the output.

Comment: I have edited the code, just use "+" after the regex, which says as match 1 or more characters of this type.

Comment: This code doesn't work. It lacks the `|` to make the regular expression an *or*.

Comment: @Elliott : I have edited it now. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Rishi Why `import java.util.*`?

Answer (score 4):

You need to separate your regular expression delimiters into a character class grouping (the `|` symbol means *or*, while the `+` means one or more). Something like,

```
String[] tokens = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?"
        .split("[ |!|,|\\?|\\.|_|'|@|]+");
for (String token : tokens) {
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

which outputs (as requested)

```
He
is
a
very
very
good
boy
isn
t
he
```

Comment: ohk understood..but one thing..will you please tell me why the exclamation,? and _ are between pipes???these aren't special characters right?

Comment: The `|` is part of the character class group; it means **or**.

Comment: @Elliott..i have edited the output.Actually i don't want a space between boy and isn.Since we use both space and , as delimiters why is it still giving the space?

Comment: Because you have `, ` which is two consecutive delimiters. Add a `+` to the class.

Comment: got it now..thanks..Elliott..:)